# AngularJS value not passing to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using ngTagsInput which has an auto-complete feature. It seems to be working very well. My problem is I want to know how to pass the query from `source="loadTags(query)"` into the directive, but query is always undefined. Query should simply be whatever text is typed in the search box.

Angular:

```
app.directive('tag', function($q) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'tag.html',
    link: function (scope) {
       scope.tags = [
          { text: 'Tag1' },
          { text: 'Tag2' },
          { text: 'Tag3' }
        ];

        scope.loadTags = function(query) {
          console.log(query)
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve([{ text: 'Tag9' },{ text: 'Tag10' }]);
          return deferred.promise;
        };
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags">
  <auto-complete source="loadTags(query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
<p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
```

My Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3UuRok?p=info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fix it for you:

Change

```
<auto-complete source="loadTags(query)"></auto-complete>
```

To

```
<auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
```

See updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/laqKKtYhBntOD3XmBufl?p=preview).